# Javascript - Getting elements by name from an element?

Tags: javascript, html

When I try the following:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                var test1 = document.getElementsByName("div1");
                alert(test1[0]);
                var test2 = test1[0].getElementsByName("div2");
                alert(test2[0]);
            }
        </script>
        <div name="div1">
            <div name="div2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work the way I intend it to. I made a form and I need to be able to get the form data in a similar manner to what I was testing with this.

Comment: Damn! my mind reading machine has a bug, ok, I give up, what was your intended way to use it?

Comment: can you use jquery? and yes what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Asaph: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.getElementsByName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, only the `document` (HTMLDocument) has the `getElementsByName` method. DOM Elements do not have that method and you cannot apply it by using them as the context.

Comment: +1, but the *name* attribute is valid for many more elements than *form* (there are 14 in total), such as all the form controls, img, a, object and so on.

Comment: @RobG: Is your comment supposed to be directed towards one of the other answers?

Comment: Ooops! Should have been a comment on the Jacob's answer. :-(

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByName` should only be called from a `document` element:

```
var test2 = document.getElementsByName('div2');
```

What's more, you really should only use the `name` attribute for form elements, not `div`s.

If you want an API that more-easily lets you do searches within a DOM element, consider using jQuery:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
          var div1 = $('#div1');
          var div2 = div1.find('#div2');
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div1">
      <div id="div2"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Of course, since `id`s must be unique document-wide, there's usually no reason to search within another element for a specific ID.  Therefore, you don't really need anything fancy like jQuery for something that simple.

Comment: If you are using simple ids jQuery is overkill. `div1 = document.getElementById("div1"); div2 = document.getElementById("div2");` You don't even need to use div1 as the context because ids are presumed to be unique.

Comment: I totally agree.  Added that as note to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not looking to get specific elements by ID though. I have a form with a variable amount of options and sub-options. I need to get them in the exact order they appear. How else can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There  is no `name` in div's attributes. Why not use id instead?